# linux syscall open() bitmask

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I want to know which purpose has the following line of code in Linux syscall `int open(const char *pathname, int flags)`:

```
if (flags & ~(O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND))
{
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: It checks if the value has any bits set that are not in those values and returns -1 if there is.

Comment: Do you know how the bitwise `~` operator works?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, it is for inverting the bits. that means, that if the value I got from the function as a parameter is none of these 6 values, I got an error with -1, right?

Comment: Not quite. If the parameter is anything else other than the ones listed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Not really, as `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_RDWR` are not bit flags per POSIX and can not be portably treated as bit flags.

Comment: Given that the cited code comes from the Linux kernel, @andrew, which is the ultimate authority on what these flags mean, for itself, something tells me that portability is irrelevant here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line checks that your file have only these properties available : 
`O_RDONLY` : read-only file 
`O_WRONLY` : write-only file 
`O_CREAT` : create the file if it does not exist 
`O_RDWR` : read-write file 
`O_TRUNC` : If  the file already exists and is a regular file and the access
              mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY)  it  will  be
              truncated to length 0. 
`O_APPEND` : the file is opened in append mode

Comment: is it the same as if ( ( flags & ~( O_RDONLY | O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_TRUNC ) ) != 0 ) {return - 1};

Comment: Yes this is the same thing !

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the actual values of that `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_RDWR` are assigned, it's not really possible to determine what that code actually does.

The code

```
if (flags & ~(O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND))
{
  return -1;
}
```

is non-portable and strictly speaking invalid outside of the actual system implementation that has access to and control of the actual values of the flags.  [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), the flags `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_RDWR` are **NOT** bit flags:

> Values for `oflag` are constructed by a bitwise-inclusive OR of flags from the following list, defined in . **Applications shall specify exactly one of the first five values (file access modes) below in the value of `oflag`**:
>
> `O_EXEC`
>   Open for execute only (non-directory files). The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a directory.
>
> `O_RDONLY`
>       Open for reading only.
>
> `O_RDWR`
>       Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO.
>
> `O_SEARCH`
>       Open directory for search only. The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a non-directory file.
>
> `O_WRONLY`
>       Open for writing only.

Since those flags are not bit-based but actual value-based, their presence or absence can not be detected via bitwise operations without knowledge of their actual values on the system in use.

This code uses more than one of those flags, violating the POSIX specification:

```
O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND
```

It can in theory produce a nonsensical bit value that can not be used in a valid bitwise comparison to anything.

The [**RATIONALE** section of the `open()` POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html#tag_16_357_08) even addresses the non-bit flag-based nature of the `open()` flags:

**RATIONALE**

> In historical implementations the value of `O_RDONLY` is zero. Because of that, it is not possible to detect the presence of `O_RDONLY` and another option. Future implementations should encode `O_RDONLY` and `O_WRONLY` as bit flags so that:
>
> `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY == O_RDWR`

That comment only makes sense if `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY` and `O_RDWR` are not bit-based flags.